# PHP Difference between settype and (int)?

Tags: php

What is the difference between:

```
$int = (int)$int;
```

and

```
settype($int,"int");
```

?

Will there be different results?

Answer (score 1):

`php` is a weakly type language. This indeed means that the compiler can
decide the type of the variable. This makes

```
$var="string";
$var=5;
```

With casting  you could do :

```
$var=(int)$var; // disaster if $var were "string"
```

Casting to a type forces variable to appear as if it were that type.

However, settype actually changes the type of the variable for the rest of the script.The prototype is :

```
bool settype ( mixed &$var , string $type )
```

However, with `settype` you have some error checking :

For example you could do

```
if (settype($var,"int"))  // You have some error checking in code.
// for php version older than 4.2.2 "integer"
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are different.

**Type casting** = To force a variable to be evaluated as a certain type.

**settype** = To change the type of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, settype modifies the type of the variable (the documentation says: "The variable being **converted**."). (int) is casting the var. 
settype can also return false as some occasions...